# Implement twitch stream on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitch

I'm currently in the process of making a website for a friends twitch stream and I'm very confused as to how I implement the twitch stream. I have created a div with the class "Twitchscreen" but I have no idea how I link to the twitch API or get the stream into the "twitchscreen" box. Please help, many thanks.

Comment: Hey - look at how its done in TeamLiquid page(view source) - they use IFrame like this: `<iframe class="videoplayer" src="http://www.twitch.tv/embed?channel=khaldor" height="478" width="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>` so it might just be as simple as that.

Comment: @JFit I appreciate the help but I'm looking to use the API as I also need a custom chat box which I know can be done with it, I just don't know how to.

Comment: can you link me the API?

Comment: Infact I don't think I need the api while trying to find the embed code of their video I found their Chat embed code. How do I find the code for their video stream? and thanks for your help JF, if you put your first comment as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Ok - do you mean the code behind it? can you use IFrames or is that not an option? can look into another way of doing it but iframe is probally the handiest solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at how its done in TeamLiquid page(view source) - they use IFrame like this:

```
<iframe class="videoplayer" src="http://www.twitch.tv/embed?channel=khaldor" height="478" width="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

so it might just be as simple as that..

To embed this on a page just put the IFrame wherever you want and change the channel querystring from khaldor to your username on twitch (for your channel).

Chat should be done the same way.

Comment: Iframe is the best solution, I just need the SRC of the channel and its done. Many thanks :D

Comment: np - What is the channel? out of interest also ;) and i'll fix source also in answer.

Comment: Its Rothmaw, its run by a friend of mine and I'm doing their site.

Comment: `<iframe class="videoplayer" src="http://www.twitch.tv/embed?channel=rothmaw" height="478" width="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>` 
Yep that works. :) - GL with the site buddy